# What performace issues can I expect while using Adobe XD using wine?

Tags: wine, performance, playonlinux, adobe

I am new to designing and my team uses Adobe XD only. It seems the only choice I have to use it on Ubuntu is using wine for it.

I want to know what performance issue will be there while using Adobe XD using wine. If it's going to work reasonably well then I'll use this method, otherwise maybe I have to go for dual boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the only choice I am left with is using wine for it.

Not true and there are 2 better methods: dual boot and virtualization. Both are always better than wine. The reason: you are using a regular  Windows.

> I want to know what performance issue will be there

I would worry about compatibility and installing 1st. Adobe XD 2019 has a "garbage" rating so ... it is not likely to run or you will need help from someone proficient with tinkering with wine.